# SafariDriver throws webdriver exception with empty message when running selenium test in Safari Browser (Monterey version)

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, safari, safaridriver

Here's my code

public static By headers = By.CssSelector("div[class*=hero-component] h1");

public int getHomePageHeaders()
{

```
     try
        {
             return webDriver.FindElements(headers).Count;
        }
     catch (Exception e)
        {
            return 0;
        }

    }
```

Other details: My tests are working properly on Chrome, Firefox, Edge and on iPhone12 but it fails on Safari.

I am using Selenium Webdriver (version 4.3.0)

Screenshot of the error:
[QuickWatch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3jvAK.png)